# Usage of Dictionary along with KeyPairValue

Tags: .net, dictionary, c++-cli, generics

I have a dictionary declared as follows:

```
public:    
     static Dictionary<String ^, List<String ^>^> ^ language_string_table;
```

so by using for each loop key and values are loaded into that (which is written by someone else). Now I need by using the same for each loop I am able to access "key" of the Dictionary alone, please help me out how to access "value" of the Dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

```
for each(KeyValuePair<String^, List<String^>^ kvp in dictionary)
{
    String^ key = kvp->Key;
    List<String^>^ value = kvp->Value;
}
```

Comment: Would you fix your `kpv` by `kvp` in `line 3` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the very basic usage of [`IEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx) interface.
Your answer is :

```
Dictionary<String ^, List<String ^>^> ^ language_string_table;

Dictionary<String ^, List<String ^>^>::Enumerator etor = language_string_table->GetEnumerator();
while(etor.MoveNext())
{
    String^ ss = etor.Current.Key;
    List<String ^>^> ^ list = etor.Current.Value;
}
//if you just want to get keys or values only
Dictionary<String ^, List<String ^>^>::KeyCollection::Enumerator keytor = language_string_table->Keys->GetEnumerator();

while(etor.MoveNext())
{
    String^ ss = keytor.Current;
}
```

But I strongly recommend you learn the iterator concept.

Also here is the [for each](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) usage in C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.

If you want to loop only over the keys, use `language_string_table->Keys`. If you want to loop only over the values, use `language_string_table->Values`. If you want to get the value for a key, use `language_string_table->default[key]`.

Comment: I need all the LIST of the values for specific key. can you please tell me the exact syntax how to fetch whole list of values for a key. if i use following syntax                         List<String^>^LangStrList;              LangStrList = LanguageData->language_string_table->Values;        it says error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'System::Collections::Generic::Dictionary<TKey,TValue>::ValueCollection ^' to 'System::Collections::Generic::List<T> ^'

Comment: `List<String^>^LangStrList = LanguageData->language_string_table->default[key];`

Comment: can you please tell me how to collect values and keys differently as well, like in a list or some other way where i can maintain separate set of keys and values.